# Display only x-axis when plotting in Igraph (in R)

Tags: r, igraph

I'm doing network visualization with igraph in R. I want to display a chronological order on the x-axis, the values on the y-axis will be set manually in order "even them out" over the plot, i.e. the numbers on the y-axis contains no information of use for the reader. Hence, I want to only display the x-axis, not the y-axis.

Here is a demonstration on my current status.

```
library(igraph)

#graph from dataframe
from <- c("One", "Two")
to <- c("Three", "Three")
fromto <- data.frame(from,to)
fromtograph <- graph_from_data_frame(fromto)

#df with coords
year <- c(400,500,600)
coords <- data.frame(as_ids(V(fromtograph)), year)
coords <- coords[order(match(coords$as_ids.V.fromtograph.., as_ids(V(fromtograph)))),]
coords <- as.matrix(data.frame(coords$year,c(300,100,200)))

plot(fromtograph,layout=coords,rescale=F,axes=T, ylim=c(0,400),xlim=c(0,800),asp=0)
```

The plot results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4ZW4.jpg). 
I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXcpX.jpg)

Best/John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a filled (white) rectangle over y-axis.

```
plot(fromtograph,layout=coords,rescale=F,axes=T, ylim=c(0,400),xlim=c(0,800),asp=0)
rect(-100, -10, 0, 450, col = "white", border = "white")
```